# Understanding AForge SOM implementation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, aforge, self-organizing-maps

Hello neural enthusiasts‎ out there,
i am a little bit confused about the SOM Learning Algorithm in AForge.
I figured out that the implementation assumes the most common case, a 2 dimensial SOM.

When i take a look at other SOM Graphics in the web, it figures out, that the position of the neuron changes over time. Similar neurons are put together.

I took a look at the source code and found out that the position of the neurons in the map is some kind of fixed. It is:

```
int wx = neuronIndex % width;
int wy = neuronIndex / width;
```

Is this just another Type of SOM with fixed possitions, or am i missinterprating something?
I also thought that mainly you want to get an informational graphic out of a SOM,
but there are no public available methods to retrieve the position of a Neuron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with AForge, but....

**EDIT:** First I was thinking that the weights are 2D and taught to resemble a grid, but this is even more educated guess: The moving grid of neurons you've seen is still not the SOM's nodes. The position of a SOM node is constant. The SOM is taught to abstract some dataset and a [Sammon's mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sammon_mapping) is likely used as a visualization method for the nodes' weights. The result is something like [this](http://www.cis.hut.fi/projects/ide/publications/html/mastersJV97/node17.html) and can probably be confused with the original SOM's lattice in which the nodes or "neurons" never move.

Note that this is still just an educated guess.